# can MySQL SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() be used as one query?

Tags: mysql

Can SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() be used as one query?

```
$query = 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM Users LIMIT 0,50';
    mysql_query($query);
    $count_query = 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS()';
    mysql_query($query);
```

If not - whats the point then?
Why not just use these two queries?

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM Users LIMIT 0,50';
$count_query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users';
```

Benefits?
Drawbacks?
Differences?

What I would prefer, is to make only one call - with a limit - and a column that has the total record count for all the records in the table.

If that is not possible - I would like to understand the difference between the two methods above.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users` has to count the rows. For some database engines this can be expensive (MyISAM keeps the table size in the metadata, so it's cheap). Since the previous query already had to scan all the rows, and you told it to remember the count, `FOUND_ROWS()` just returns that saved count.

However, unless you use `LIMIT` in the first query, there's little point in using `FOUND_ROWS()`. You could simply use:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

The main benefit of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is when the query contains a `LIMIT` clause. `FOUND_ROWS()` returns the total number of rows that would have been returned without that option. This is useful for pagination, since you can calculate the total number of pages from this, without having to do another query that uses `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Is it two separate calls either way?

Comment: Yes, the call to get `FOUND_ROWS()` has to be a separate query.

Comment: was thinking it could be passed in a separate row with the result or something... you know like SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS AS MY_COUNT

Comment: You could do that by using `COUNT(*)` along with `GROUP BY` and `WITH ROLLUP`. You'll get an extra row with the grouping columns = `NULL` and the count will be the total.

Comment: But what's wrong with just using `mysql_num_rows()`? That doesn't perform an extra query.

Comment: Barmar - if you want to set a limit to your query - and need to also know the total records - 'mysql_num_rows()' will not represent all records in table.

Comment: Or maybe i'm confused - that's why I am here.
I guess two calls are not the end of the world - but seems a good idea to make only one call when you can. If you are aware of a way to set a limit and also pull the total number of records for the same table - I would appreciate knowing how. Thank you.

Comment: None of the queries in your question have a `LIMIT` clause, so I'm confused about what specifically you're asking about. AFAIK, if you use `LIMIT`, there's no way to get the non-limited row count without two queries. But if you don't use `LIMIT`, you have several options.

Comment: You are probably right about that - sorry - I should have added the LIMIT to be clear. It is usually the reason for the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS - as you said. For sure I meant with a LIMIT. Let me make the question clearer. Let me know what you think. Thank you.